# ar_toolkit Marker

Tags: ros, markers

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Are there anywhere finished standard markers for the ar_toolkit to download and to print?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/33948/ar_toolkit-marker/) by [Janina](https://answers.ros.org/users/1871/janina/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2012-05-14

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you check out the [ccny_vision](http://www.ros.org/wiki/ccny_vision) stack you have a bunch of markers in the directory ar_pose/data/4x4/4x4_ps.tar.gz

---

Originally posted by [Stephan](https://answers.ros.org/users/266/stephan/) with karma: 1924 on 2012-05-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1